# in .ajax calls, is async: true assumed by default?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Some of the code I've seen specifies `async:true` and other code `async:false`. If I don't declare `async` at all, does it default to `true`, so ajax calls are by default asynchronous?

Comment: why not check the manual first, took me 2 seconds to google it

Comment: You do realize what the A in AJAX stands for right?

Comment: a stands for asyncronus, so there is no matter of question about it.

Comment: @Jethik, `A` in `AJAX` should be `A`, not `a`. ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at [**the documentation of `jQuery.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) *(quoting*) :

> **By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously** *(i.e. this is set to
>   `true` by default)*. If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option
>   to `false`.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual:

> Default: true

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

Yup. Ajax calls are asynchronous by nature and defaults to true.

Answer (score 3):

> async
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option
>   to false. Cross-domain requests and
>   dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note
>   that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the
>   request is active.

Answer (score 2):

Requests are `async:true` by default **but** if you call `ajaxSetup` this way...

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

...at any time before calling `$.ajax` without specifying the `async` option, the async configuration specified in `ajaxSetup` will be used. With the setup code above, the request would be synchronous.